# Does tomcat write the http access log for a 503 error

Tags: http, tomcat

HTTP 503 errors occur during heavy load during performance testing of two tomcat servers.  On the tomcat servers, log entries stop appearing in their access logs at the same time that the HTTP 503 errors start occurring.

There is a load balancer in front of two tomcat servers.  I do not have access to the file system on the load balancer and cannot tell if the HTTP 503 errors are coming from the tomcat servers or the load balancer.

The question is whether tomcat would write the access log when it returns an HTTP 503 error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `OutOfMemoryErrors`. If those occur, all kinds of things can stop working.